# Create new dummy variable columns from categorical variable

Tags: r

I have a several data sets with 75,000 observations and a `type` variable that can take on a value 0-4.  I want to add five new dummy variables to each data set for all types.  The best way I could come up with to do this is as follows:

```
# For the 'binom' data set create dummy variables for all types in all data sets
binom.dummy.list<-list()
for(i in 0:4){
    binom.dummy.list[[i+1]]<-sapply(binom$type,function(t) ifelse(t==i,1,0))
}

# Add and merge data
binom.dummy.df<-as.data.frame(do.call("cbind",binom.dummy.list))
binom.dummy.df<-transform(binom.dummy.df,id=1:nrow(binom))
binom<-merge(binom,binom.dummy.df,by="id")
```

While this works, it is incredibly slow (the merge function has even crashed a few times). Is there a more efficient way to do this?  Perhaps this functionality is part of a package that I am not familiar with?

Comment: `ifelse` is vectorized, so if I understand your code correctly, you don't need that `sapply`. And I wouldn't use merge - I would use SQLite or PostgreSQL. Some sample data would help too :-)

Answer (score 49, accepted):

R has a "sub-language" to translate formulas into design matrix, and in the spirit of the language you can take advantage of it. It's fast and concise. Example: you have a cardinal predictor x, a categorical predictor catVar, and a response y.

```
> binom <- data.frame(y=runif(1e5), x=runif(1e5), catVar=as.factor(sample(0:4,1e5,TRUE)))
> head(binom)
          y          x catVar
1 0.5051653 0.34888390      2
2 0.4868774 0.85005067      2
3 0.3324482 0.58467798      2
4 0.2966733 0.05510749      3
5 0.5695851 0.96237936      1
6 0.8358417 0.06367418      2
```

You just do

```
> A <- model.matrix(y ~ x + catVar,binom) 
> head(A)
  (Intercept)          x catVar1 catVar2 catVar3 catVar4
1           1 0.34888390       0       1       0       0
2           1 0.85005067       0       1       0       0
3           1 0.58467798       0       1       0       0
4           1 0.05510749       0       0       1       0
5           1 0.96237936       1       0       0       0
6           1 0.06367418       0       1       0       0
```

Done.

Comment: Any easy way of going the opposite direction-ie you have the dummy variables but want to collapse them into one variable?

Comment: note that if you change the type of contrasts used you will get different results.  Also, you will get different answers for ordered an unordered factors. The default contrasts set in R is `options(contrasts = c("contr.treatment", "contr.poly"))`.  See `?contrasts` to add to your confusion.

Comment: Also note that the example here has 5 categories, because the index starts at 0 `sample(0:4, 1e5 , TRUE)`.  I don't think it is possible in base R to automatically generate all the levels of dummy variables.  This particular example happens to omit any samples of 0, which would appear as a row of zeros in the model matrix.

Comment: This method drops rows with NAs, which makes me prefer Joshua Ullrich's answer.  And to clarify geneorama's point, for n levels of a variable you only need n-1 dummy variables to represent the information.  (If for some reason you wanted to hack `model.matrix()` to explicitly represent all columns, you could add a reference level with no members as in `levels(binom$catVar) <- c("dummy", levels(binom$catVar)); A <- model.matrix(y ~ x + catVar,binom, contrasts = "contr.treatment")` but this redundancy seems risky  if you're doing modeling.)

Comment: if you do not want intercept then use `A <- model.matrix(y ~ x + catVar -1, binom)`

Answer (score 24):

Drew, this is much faster and shouldn't cause any crashes.

```
> binom <- data.frame(data=runif(1e5),type=sample(0:4,1e5,TRUE))
> for(t in unique(binom$type)) {
+   binom[paste("type",t,sep="")] <- ifelse(binom$type==t,1,0)
+ }
> head(binom)
        data type type2 type4 type1 type3 type0
1 0.11787309    2     1     0     0     0     0
2 0.11884046    4     0     1     0     0     0
3 0.92234950    4     0     1     0     0     0
4 0.44759259    1     0     0     1     0     0
5 0.01669651    2     1     0     0     0     0
6 0.33966184    3     0     0     0     1     0
```

Comment: nice solution. May i suggest, before the "paste" to include a little "make.names" in case the level names contain some litigious character.

Answer (score 16):

What about using model.matrix()?

```
> binom <- data.frame(data=runif(1e5),type=sample(0:4,1e5,TRUE))
> head(binom)
       data type
1 0.1412164    2
2 0.8764588    2
3 0.5559061    4
4 0.3890109    3
5 0.8725753    3
6 0.8358100    1
> inds <- model.matrix(~ factor(binom$type) - 1)
> head(inds)
  factor(binom$type)0 factor(binom$type)1 factor(binom$type)2 factor(binom$type)3 factor(binom$type)4
1                   0                   0                   1                   0                   0
2                   0                   0                   1                   0                   0
3                   0                   0                   0                   0                   1
4                   0                   0                   0                   1                   0
5                   0                   0                   0                   1                   0
6                   0                   1                   0                   0                   0
```

Comment: what if the type variable has NA values as well? How can we keep the NA values as a separate variable in addition to 1 and 0?

Comment: Code the NA values to something other than NA.

Answer (score 3):

If you're open to using the [data.table](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table) package, [mltools](https://github.com/ben519/mltools) has a one_hot() method.

```
library(data.table)
library(mltools)

binom <- data.table(y=runif(1e5), x=runif(1e5), catVar=as.factor(sample(0:4,1e5,TRUE)))
one_hot(binom)

                 y          x catVar_0 catVar_1 catVar_2 catVar_3 catVar_4
     1: 0.90511891 0.83045050        0        0        1        0        0
     2: 0.91375984 0.73273830        0        0        0        1        0
     3: 0.01926608 0.10301409        0        0        1        0        0
     4: 0.48691138 0.24428157        0        1        0        0        0
     5: 0.60660396 0.09132816        0        0        1        0        0
    ---                                                                   
 99996: 0.12908356 0.26157731        0        1        0        0        0
 99997: 0.96397273 0.98959000        0        1        0        0        0
 99998: 0.16818414 0.37460941        1        0        0        0        0
 99999: 0.72610508 0.72055867        1        0        0        0        0
100000: 0.89710998 0.24155507        0        0        0        0        1
```

Usage

```
one_hot(dt, cols = "auto", sparsifyNAs = FALSE, 
        naCols = FALSE, dropCols = TRUE,
        dropUnusedLevels = FALSE)
```

Which column(s) should be one-hot-encoded? cols = "auto" encodes all unordered factor columns. Therefore, the command below is equivalent. This is only important when the data.table contains factors that should not be encoded.

```
one_hot(binom, cols="catVar")
```

Answer (score 2):

The recipes package can also be quite powerful to do this. The example below is quite verbose but it can be really clean as soon as you add more preprocessing steps.

```
library(recipes)

binom <- data.frame(y = runif(1e5), 
                    x = runif(1e5),
                    catVar = as.factor(sample(0:4, 1e5, TRUE))) # use the example from gappy
head(binom)

new_data <- recipe(y ~ ., data = binom) %>% 
  step_dummy(catVar) %>% # add dummy variable
  prep(training = binom) %>% # apply the preprocessing steps (could be more than just adding dummy variables)
  bake(newdata = binom) # apply the recipe to new data
head(new_data)
```

Other step examples are step_scale, step_center, step_pca, etc.

Answer (score 1):

I did not have good luck with `model.matrix()` function as it was omitting some factor levels for whatever reason. However, i have had good luck with this simple function from `library(fastDummies)`:

Columns that are converted into binary dummy variables have to be categorical.

`fastDummies::dummy_cols(fastDummies_example, select_columns = "numbers", remove_selected_columns = "numbers")`

Answer (score 0):

The nnet package for single-layer neural networks (which don't understand factors) has a conversion command: class.ind.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the package called `dummies`

```
binom <- data.frame(y=runif(1e5), x=runif(1e5), catVar=as.factor(sample(0:4,1e5,TRUE)))
head(binom)

          y          x catVar
1 0.4143348 0.09721401      1
2 0.3140782 0.54340539      3
3 0.1262037 0.51820499      2
4 0.7159850 0.13167720      3
5 0.8203528 0.94116026      3
6 0.2169781 0.82020216      1
```

Solution:

```
library(dummies)
binom<-dummy.data.frame(binom)
head(binom)

          y          x catVar0 catVar1 catVar2 catVar3 catVar4
1 0.4143348 0.09721401       0       1       0       0       0
2 0.3140782 0.54340539       0       0       0       1       0
3 0.1262037 0.51820499       0       0       1       0       0
4 0.7159850 0.13167720       0       0       0       1       0
5 0.8203528 0.94116026       0       0       0       1       0
6 0.2169781 0.82020216       0       1       0       0       0
```