# Creating categorical variables from mutually exclusive dummy variables

Tags: r, categorical-data, dummy-variable

My question regards an elaboration on a previously answered question about [combining multiple dummy variables into a single categorical variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8419357/combine-multiple-categorical-variables-in-one-dummy-variable).

In the question previously asked, the categorical variable was created from dummy variables that were NOT mutually exclusive.  For my case, my dummy variables are mutually exclusive because they represent crossed experimental conditions in a 2X2 between-subjects factorial design (that also has a within subjects component which I'm not addressing here), so I don't think `interaction` does what I need to do.

For example, my data might look like this:

```
id   conditionA    conditionB    conditionC     conditionD
1    NA            1             NA             NA
2    1             NA            NA             NA
3    NA            NA            1              NA
4    NA            NA            NA             1
5    NA            2             NA             NA
6    2             NA            NA             NA
7    NA            NA            2              NA
8    NA            NA            NA             2
```

I'd like to now make categorical variables that combine ACROSS different types of conditions.  For example, people who had values for condition A and B might be coded with one categorical variable, and people who had values for condition C and D.

```
id   conditionA    conditionB    conditionC     conditionD  factor1    factor2
1    NA            1             NA             NA          1          NA
2    1             NA            NA             NA          1          NA
3    NA            NA            1              NA          NA         1
4    NA            NA            NA             1           NA         1
5    NA            2             NA             NA          2          NA
6    2             NA            NA             NA          2          NA
7    NA            NA            2              NA          NA         2
8    NA            NA            NA             2           NA         2
```

Right now, I'm doing this using `ifelse()` statements, which quite simply is a hot mess (and doesn't always work).  Please help! There's probably some super-obvious "easier way."

EDIT:

The kinds of `ifelse` commands that I am using are as follows:

```
attach(df)
df$factor<-ifelse(conditionA==1 | conditionB==1, 1, NA)
df$factor<-ifelse(conditionA==2 | conditionB==2, 2, df$factor)
```

In reality, I'm combining across 6-8 columns each time, so a more elegant solution would help a lot.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Update (2019): Please use [`dplyr::coalesce()`](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/coalesce.html), it works pretty much the same.

My [R package](https://github.com/muelleki/kimisc) has a convenience function that allows to choose the first non-`NA` value for each element in a list of vectors:

```
#library(devtools)
#install_github('kimisc', 'muelleki')
library(kimisc)

df$factor1 <- with(df, coalesce.na(conditionA, conditionB))
```

(I'm not sure if this works if `conditionA` and `conditionB` are factors. Convert them to numerics before using `as.numeric(as.character(...))` if necessary.)

Otherwise, you could give `interaction` a try, combined with recoding of the levels of the resulting factor -- but to me it looks like you're more interested in the first solution:

```
df$conditionAB <- with(df, interaction(coalesce.na(conditionA, 0), 
                                       coalesce.na(conditionB, 0)))
levels(df$conditionAB) <- c('A', 'B')
```

Comment: Thanks! Good catch...a typo in the last 2 rows when I was making up sample data.

Comment: @roody: Can `conditionD` ever contain the value, say, 3? What should happen then?

Comment: No, they are all two level factor variables -- 1 and 2 are just the values assigned to them by Qualtrics, but it's always a dichtomous choice.

Comment: Hi there - I've added more examples. R won't allow me to install your package, though. It gives me an error that says `sh: make: command not found
ERROR: compilation failed for package 'kimisc'`

Comment: @roody: Are you on Windows? Then you might need to install [Rtools](http://cran.r-project.org/bin/windows/Rtools/). Otherwise, install the GNU toolchain (`make`, `g++`, ...). Or simply copy the code from [here](https://github.com/muelleki/kimisc/blob/master/R/coalesce_na.R)...

Comment: @roody, another way of thanking is to *up-vote* helpful answers.

Answer (score 1):

Well, I think you can do it simply with `ifelse`, something like :

```
factor1 <- ifelse(is.na(conditionA), conditionB, conditionA)
```

Another way could be :

```
factor1 <- conditionA
factor1[is.na(factor1)] <- conditionB
```

And a third solution, certainly more pratical if you have more than two columns conditions :

```
factor1 <- apply(df[,c("conditionA","conditionB")], 1, sum, na.rm=TRUE)
```

Comment: Hi @juba--I like the simplicity of the third solution...but how do I change all of the relevant columns to numeric if R reads them in as factor? The command `df[cols] <- as.numeric(as.matrix(df[cols]))
` doesn't appear to work (when `cols` is a list of column numbers).

Answer (score 1):

I think this function gives you what you need (admittedly, this is a quick hack).

```
to_indicator <- function(x, grp)
{
    apply(tbl, 1,
          function (x)
          {
              idx <- which(!is.na(x))
              nm <- names(idx)
              if (nm %in% grp)
                x[idx]
              else
                NA
          })
}
```

And here is it's used with the example data you provide.

```
tbl <- read.table(header=TRUE, text="
conditionA    conditionB    conditionC     conditionD
NA            1             NA             NA
1             NA            NA             NA
NA            NA            1              NA
NA            NA            NA             1
NA            2             NA             NA
2             NA            NA             NA
NA            NA            2              NA
NA            NA            NA             2")
tbl <- data.frame(tbl)

(tbl <- cbind(tbl,
              factor1=to_indicator(tbl, c("conditionA", "conditionB")),
              factor2=to_indicator(tbl, c("conditionC", "conditionD"))))
```