# Convert various dummy/logical variables into a single categorical variable/factor from their name in R

Tags: r, data-transform

My question has strong similarities with [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16135316/creating-categorical-variables-from-mutually-exclusive-dummy-variables) and [this other one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29870994/dummy-variables-to-single-categorical-variable-factor-in-r), but my dataset is a little bit different and I can't seem to make those solutions work. Please excuse me if I misunderstood something and this question is redundant.

I have a dataset such as this one:

```
df <- data.frame(
  id = c(1:5),
  conditionA = c(1, NA, NA, NA, 1),
  conditionB = c(NA, 1, NA, NA, NA),
  conditionC = c(NA, NA, 1, NA, NA),
  conditionD = c(NA, NA, NA, 1, NA)
  )
# id conditionA conditionB conditionC conditionD
# 1  1          1         NA         NA         NA
# 2  2         NA          1         NA         NA
# 3  3         NA         NA          1         NA
# 4  4         NA         NA         NA          1
# 5  5          1         NA         NA         NA
```

(Note that apart from these columns, I have a lot of other columns that shouldn't be affected by the current manipulation.)

So, I observe that `conditionA`, `conditionB`, `conditionC` and `conditionD` are mutually exclusives and should be better presented as a single categorical variable, i.e. `factor`, that should look like this :

```
#   id       type
# 1  1 conditionA
# 2  2 conditionB
# 3  3 conditionC
# 4  4 conditionD
# 5  5 conditionA
```

---

I have investigated using `gather` or `unite` from `tidyr`, but it doesn't correspond to this case (with `unite`, we lose the information from the variable name).

I tried using `kimisc::coalescence.na`, as suggested in the first referred answer, but 1. I need first to set a factor value based on the name for each column, 2. it doesn't work as expected, only including the first column :

```
library(kimisc)
# first, factor each condition with a specific label
df$conditionA <- df$conditionA %>%
  factor(levels = 1, labels = "conditionA")
df$conditionB <- df$conditionB %>%
  factor(levels = 1, labels = "conditionB")
df$conditionC <- df$conditionC %>%
  factor(levels = 1, labels = "conditionC")
df$conditionD <- df$conditionD %>%
  factor(levels = 1, labels = "conditionD")

# now coalesce.na to merge into a single variable
df$type <- coalesce.na(df$conditionA, df$conditionB, df$conditionC, df$conditionD)

df
#   id conditionA conditionB conditionC conditionD       type
# 1  1 conditionA       <NA>       <NA>       <NA> conditionA 
# 2  2       <NA> conditionB       <NA>       <NA>       <NA> 
# 3  3       <NA>       <NA> conditionC       <NA>       <NA> 
# 4  4       <NA>       <NA>       <NA> conditionD       <NA> 
# 5  5 conditionA       <NA>       <NA>       <NA> conditionA
```

I tried the other suggestions from the second question, but haven't found one that would bring me the expected result...

Comment: Encoding a dummy as `NA`/`1` instead of `0`/`1` has no upside that I know of. I've been seeing this a lot on SO lately.

Comment: @Frank: Actually, it was not thought as a dummy variable (e.g. for regression): I manually entered all those data in Excel, putting a `1` each time a condition was satisfied (and didn't bother to fill the rest with `0`). I'm not sure if I should call that a dummy variable (but that's the term I've been encountering)...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df %>% gather(type, value, -id) %>% na.omit() %>% select(-value) %>% arrange(id)
```

Which gives:

```
#  id       type
#1  1 conditionA
#2  2 conditionB
#3  3 conditionC
#4  4 conditionD
#5  5 conditionA
```

---

**Update**

To handle the case you detailed in the comments, you could do the operation on the desired portion of the data frame and then `left_join()` the other columns:

```
df %>% 
  select(starts_with("condition"), id) %>% 
  gather(type, value, -id) %>% 
  na.omit() %>% 
  select(-value) %>% 
  left_join(., df %>% select(-starts_with("condition"))) %>%
  arrange(id)
```

Comment: Great! I hadn't thought about combining `gather` with `na.omit` to obtain this result!
Now, I still have a big issue : the actual dataset has a LOT more columns, and a lot of them are partially empty. `na.omit` would then delete these observations, even though they DO have a condition set...
(Also, in `gather(type, value, -id)`, if I have to exclude (`-x`) something like 70 columns, is there a quick way to do it?)

Comment: @SergeBibauw Would something like this work for you: `df %>% select(starts_with("condition"), id) %>% gather(type, value, -id) %>% na.omit() %>% select(-value) %>% left_join(., df %>% select(-starts_with("condition"))) %>% arrange(id)` ?

Comment: Thanks! I indeed figured I needed to `select` only wanted columns, apply the `gather` etc. process, and then "reinject" the result into the original data frame.

Answer (score 5):

You can also try:

```
colnames(df)[2:5][max.col(!is.na(df[,2:5]))]
#[1] "conditionA" "conditionB" "conditionC" "conditionD" "conditionA"
```

The above works if one and only one column has a value other than `NA` for each row. If the values of a row can be all `NA`s, then you can try:

```
mat<-!is.na(df[,2:5])
colnames(df)[2:5][max.col(mat)*(NA^!rowSums(mat))]
```

Comment: Pretty sure this is the most efficient. 4x as fast as Stephen's on `big_df <- rbind(df,df); for (i in 1:18) big_df <- rbind(big_df,big_df)`

Comment: It does work quite well, except that, if a row has `<NA>` in all four conditions, then this code gives it one of the four conditions (not always the same, I don't even understand well why), when it should rather leave the resulting value to `<NA>`. Is there a way to avoid that?

Answer (score 1):

```
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)

df <- df %>%
  gather(type, count, -id)
df <- df[complete.cases(df),][,-3]
df[order(df$id),]
   id       type
1   1 conditionA
7   2 conditionB
13  3 conditionC
19  4 conditionD
5   5 conditionA
```

Comment: A more `dplyr`-esque approach would be `df %>% gather(type, value, -id) %>% na.omit() %>% select(-value) %>% arrange(id)`