# Transforming dummy variable into label vector

Tags: r

I have a dataframe like this:

```
> dput(df_before)
structure(list(ID = 1:4, White = c(1L, 0L, 0L, 0L), Black = c(0L, 
1L, 0L, 0L), Asian = c(0L, 0L, 1L, 1L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-4L))
```

Right now the 'Race' variable is encoded as a dummy variable, but I would like it to look like this:

```
> dput(df_after)
structure(list(ID = 1:4, Race = c("White", "Black", "Asian", 
"Asian")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -4L))
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30333401/convert-various-dummy-logical-variables-into-a-single-categorical-variable-facto

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `case_when` function from the `tidyverse` to
reshape the dataframe.

```
library(tidyverse)
df_after <- df_before %>% 
  mutate(Race = case_when(White == 1 ~ "White",
                          Black == 1 ~ "Black",
                          Asian == 1 ~ "Asian"))
```

Answer (score 0):

In base R, using dynamic rather than static:

```
cbind(df[1], Race = names(df[-1])[max.col(df[-1])])

  ID  Race
1  1 White
2  2 Black
3  3 Asian
4  4 Asian
```