# Create mutually exclusive dummy variables from categorical variable in R

Tags: r

A while ago, I asked a question about creating a categorical variable from [mutually exclusive dummy variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16135316/creating-categorical-variables-from-mutually-exclusive-dummy-variables). Now, it turns out I want to do the opposite.

How would one go about creating dummy variables in a long-form dataset from a single categorical variable (`time`)? e.g. the dataframe below...

```
id     time   
1      1       
1      2       
1      3      
1      4
```

would become...

```
id     time    time_dummy_1   time_dummy_2    time_dummy_3  time_dummy_4
1      1       1              0               0             0
1      2       0              1               0             0
1      3       0              0               1             0
1      4       0              0               0             1
```

I'm sure this is trivial (and please let me know if this question is a duplicate -- I'm not sure it is, but will happily remove if so). Thanks!

Comment: Can you give an example input/output? It's not entirely clear.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11952706/generate-a-dummy-variable-in-r

Comment: if you use `library(tidyr)` and `library(plyr)`, it's simply: `df %>% mutate(time2=paste0("time_dummy_",time)) %>% spread(time2, id, fill=0)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your data is

```
id <- c(1,1,1,1)
time <- c(1,2,3,4)
df <- data.frame(id,time)
```

you can try

```
time <- as.character(time)
unique.time <- as.character(unique(df$time))
# Create a dichotomous dummy-variable for each time
x <- sapply(unique.time, function(x)as.numeric(df$time == x))
```

or

```
time.f = factor(time)
dummies = model.matrix(~time.f)
```

Comment: +1 for `model.matrix`! That's really neat. [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11952708/1446892) says `model.matrix` treats time=1 as the default or intercept value, but how do you "change how the "default" is chosen by messing with contrasts.arg in model.matrix"? And how do you assign the `dummy_time_1` column in the table?

Comment: @Synergist ; you can suppress the intercept by adding`0` or `-1`. So `model.matrix(~0 + time.f)`. For more variables it become a little trickier to get all levelx of each factor .. see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4560459/all-levels-of-a-factor-in-a-model-matrix-in-r?/4569239#4569239) for a neat way

Answer (score 4):

You can try the `dummies` library.

### R Code:

```
# Creating the data frame
# id <- c(1,1,1,1)
# time <- c(1,2,3,4)
# data <- data.frame(id, time)

install.packages("dummies")
library(dummies)
data <- cbind(data, dummy(data$time))
```

### Output:

```
  id time data1 data2 data3 data4
   1    1     1     0     0     0
   1    2     0     1     0     0
   1    3     0     0     1     0
   1    4     0     0     0     1
```

Further you can rename the newly added dummy variable headers to suit your needs

### R Code:

```
# Rename column headers
colnames(data)[colnames(data)=="data1"] <- "time_dummy_1"
colnames(data)[colnames(data)=="data2"] <- "time_dummy_2"
colnames(data)[colnames(data)=="data3"] <- "time_dummy_3"
colnames(data)[colnames(data)=="data4"] <- "time_dummy_4"
```

### Output:

```
  id time time_dummy_1 time_dummy_2 time_dummy_3 time_dummy_4
   1    1            1            0            0            0
   1    2            0            1            0            0
   1    3            0            0            1            0
   1    4            0            0            0            1
```

Hope this helps.