# Creating a matrix of hash values, with zeros and ones

Tags: r, matrix, hash

Have a data-set that looks like this, but with 250000 rows:

```
a
a
b
c
c
c
c
etc.
```

I would like to make a matrix with zero and one values for each row, whether they appear in the columns, which are a,b,c etc.

Have attached an example to make things clearer:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B3938jUqpIbnRUoyS092aFNSZ0k/view?usp=sharing

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Thanks!

Comment: Oh, this needs to be done in R, thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3384506/create-new-dummy-variable-columns-from-categorical-variable

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5048638/automatically-expanding-an-r-factor-into-a-collection-of-1-0-indicator-variables

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30622422/create-mutually-exclusive-dummy-variables-from-categorical-variable-in-r

Comment: take a look at `?nnet::class.ind`