# Covert dummy variables to single categorical in R?

Tags: r

Similar questions have been asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30333401/r-convert-various-dummy-logical-variables-into-a-single-categorical-variable-f), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16135316/creating-categorical-variables-from-mutually-exclusive-dummy-variables), and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29870994/dummy-variables-to-single-categorical-variable-factor-in-r). However, they don't seem to cover exactly what I need. For example, if I have a dataset like so:

```
df <- data.frame(
  x = rnorm(10),
  y = rnorm(10),
  a = c(0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,1,0),
  b = c(1,1,1,1,0,0,1,0,0,0),
  c = c(0,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0),
  z = c(1,1,1,1,1,0,1,0,1,0)
)
```

What I'm trying to do is convert the variables `a`, `b`, and `c` to a single categorical where the levels are `a`, `b`, and `c`. But as you can see, sometimes 2 variables occur in the same row. So, what I'm trying to achieve is a data frame that would look something like this:

```
df <- data.frame(
  x = rnorm(10),
  y = rnorm(10),
  a = c(0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,1,0),
  b = c(1,1,1,1,0,0,1,0,0,0),
  c = c(0,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0),
  z = c(“b”,“b,c”,“b”,“a,b,c”,“a”,0,“b”,0,“a”,0)
)
```

I tried using :

```
apply(df[,c("a","b", "c")], 1, sum, na.rm=TRUE)
```

which sums the amount of each variable... but I'm not sure how to combine 2 (or more) variables into a single factor level!?

Any suggestions as to how I could do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Loop over the selected columns by row (`MARGIN = 1`), subset the column names where the value is 1 and `paste` them together

```
df$z <-  apply(df[c('a', 'b', 'c')], 1, function(x) toString(names(x)[x ==1]))
df$z
#[1] "b"       "b, c"    "b"       "a, b, c" "a"       ""        "b"       ""        "a"       ""
```

If we want to change the `""` to '0'

```
df$z[df$z == ''] <- '0'
```

For a solution with purrr and dplyr:

```
df %>% mutate(z = pmap_chr(select(., a, b, c), ~  {v1 <- c(...); toString(names(v1)[v1 == 1])}))
```

Comment: @GuedesBF Here is a way `df %>% mutate(z = pmap_chr(select(., a, b, c), ~  {v1 <- c(...); toString(names(v1)[v1 == 1])}))`

Comment: Thats it. I was missin the `c(...)' function.

Comment: @GuedesBF there was a typo.  I updatedd it

Comment: I suggested incorporating that into the answer for future reference

Comment: @GuedesBF It's okay.  I think I would leave it for others to answer