# R: Expanding an R factor into dummy columns for every factor level

Tags: r, bigdata, categorical-data, dummy-data, model.matrix

I have a quite big data frame in R with two columns. I am trying to make out of the `Code` column (`factor` type with 858 levels) the dummy variables. The problem is that the R Studio always crashed when I am trying to do that.

```
> str(d)
'data.frame':   649226 obs. of  2 variables:
 $ User: int  210 210 210 210 269 317 317 317 317 326 ...
 $ Code      : Factor w/ 858 levels "AA02","AA03",..: 164 494 538 626 464 496 435 464 475 163 ...
```

The `User` column is not unique, meaning that there can be several rows with the same `User`. Doesn't matter if in the end the amount of rows remains the same or the rows with the same `User` are merged into one row having several columns non-empty with the count of `Code`s.

I found couple of solutions that work for a smaller dataset, but not for mine.

- Tried using `model.matrix`, but the R Studio just crashes

  ```
  m <- model.matrix( ~ Code, data = d)
  ```

  Found here [Automatically expanding an R factor into a collection of 1/0 indicator variables for every factor level](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5048638/automatically-expanding-an-r-factor-into-a-collection-of-1-0-indicator-variables)
- Tried `for` cycle with `ifelse`, but the code run for 4 hours and then I noticed that the R Studio crashed.

  ```
  for (t in unique(d$Code)) {
    d[paste("Code", t, sep = "")] <- ifelse(d$Code == t, 1, 0)
  }
  ```

  Found here [Create new dummy variable columns from categorical variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3384506/create-new-dummy-variable-columns-from-categorical-variable)

Would be great if you can recommend me some method which is fast and working for such type of data.

Thanks!

Comment: If I am understanding you correctly, you want to take a data frame with two columns and add `858 - 1` columns of dummy variables for the factor levels in `Code`? ... why?

Comment: What do you mean by "R Studio crashed"? Is there an error message? Do you have sufficient RAM for a 649226*859 data.frame?

Comment: @rawr, Yes, you are correct. I wanted to run methods (e.g. `Recommender`) from the `recommenderlab` package. They are describing that you have to have this kind of matrix of user-item purchases to make predictions what users can buy in future. Page 21, [recommenderlab package] (http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/recommenderlab/vignettes/recommenderlab.pdf)

Comment: look at the command `disjunctive` from the library `sampling`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This worked for me perfectly:

```
library(reshape2)
m <- acast(data = d, User ~ Code)
```

The only thing was that it produced `NA`s, instead of `0`s, but this can be easily changed with this:

```
m[is.na(m)] <- 0
```

Comment: If you want 0s instead of NAs, try the fill option: ```m <- acast(data = d, User ~ Code, fill = 0)```