# Dummy coding syntax (one hot coding question)

Tags: r, dplyr

I have sample data that looks like this:

```
id <- c("1a","2c","3d","4f","5g","6e","7f","8q","9r","10v","11x","12l")
O <- c(1,1,0,1,1,0,0,1,0,1,0,1)
dg1 <- c("A02","A84","B12","C94","D37","D12","D68","E12","F48","H12","Z83","")
dg2 <- c("B18","N34","A02","M01","B12","J02","K52","","I10","","","B18")
df <- cbind.data.frame(id,O,dg1,dg2)
```

I am trying to get a data frame that looks like this so that I can do a univariate logistic regression on O against each variable.

```
A02 <- c(1,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0)
A84 <- c(0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0)
B12 <- c(0,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0)
B18 <- c(1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1)
C94 <- c(0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0)
D12 <- c(0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0)
D37 <- c(0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0)
D68 <- c(0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0)
E12 <- c(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0)
F48 <- c(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0)
H12 <- c(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0)
I10 <- c(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0)
J02 <- c(0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0)
K52 <- c(0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0)
M01 <- c(0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0)
N34 <- c(0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0)
Z83 <- c(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0)

df <- cbind.data.frame(df,A02,A84,B12,B18,C94,D12,D37,D68,E12,F48,H12,I10,J02,K52,M01,N34,Z83)
```

I've attempted to follow the code [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3384506/create-new-dummy-variable-columns-from-categorical-variable) and [here](https://www.marsja.se/create-dummy-variables-in-r/) but ran into issues that I wasn't sure how to fix. Can anyone point out my mistake/misunderstanding? I would prefer to have a solution in dplyr or base, but really willing to try anything.

Attempts:

```
dumbo <- model.matrix(id ~ dg1+dg2,df)

library(recipes)
dumber <- df %>% recipe(id ~ .) %>%
  step_dummy(dg1:dg2,
             one_hot = TRUE)  %>% 
  prep() %>% bake(new_data=NULL)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
df %>%
  pivot_longer(-c(id, O), names_to = NULL) %>%
  filter(value != "") %>% 
  pivot_wider(
    id_cols = c(id, O),
    names_from = value,
    values_from = value,
    values_fn = length, 
    values_fill = 0, 
    names_sort = TRUE
  )

# A tibble: 12 x 19
   id        O   A02   A84   B12   B18   C94   D12   D37   D68   E12   F48   H12   I10   J02   K52
   <chr> <dbl> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int>
 1 1a        1     1     0     0     1     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
 2 2c        1     0     1     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
 3 3d        0     1     0     1     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
 4 4f        1     0     0     0     0     1     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
 5 5g        1     0     0     1     0     0     0     1     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
 6 6e        0     0     0     0     0     0     1     0     0     0     0     0     0     1     0
 7 7f        0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     1     0     0     0     0     0     1
 8 8q        1     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     1     0     0     0     0     0
 9 9r        0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     1     0     1     0     0
10 10v       1     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     1     0     0     0
11 11x       0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
12 12l       1     0     0     0     1     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
# ... with 3 more variables: M01 <int>, N34 <int>, Z83 <int>
```

Comment: just as a future reference for anyone, if there are multiple of the same ID's, mutate(X=row_number()) before the pivot longer, then select(-X) after the pivot wider works well.

Answer (score 0):

```
library(tidyverse)


df %>% 
  left_join(
  df %>% 
    pivot_longer(c(dg1, dg2)) %>% 
    filter(value != "") %>% 
    pivot_wider(c(id, O), names_from = value) %>% 
    mutate(across(c(A02:Z83), ~if_else(is.na(.x), 0, 1)))
  )

Joining, by = c("id", "O")
    id O dg1 dg2 A02 B18 A84 N34 B12 C94 M01 D37 D12 J02 D68 K52 E12 F48 I10 H12 Z83
1   1a 1 A02 B18   1   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
2   2c 1 A84 N34   0   0   1   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
3   3d 0 B12 A02   1   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
4   4f 1 C94 M01   0   0   0   0   0   1   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
5   5g 1 D37 B12   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
6   6e 0 D12 J02   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
7   7f 0 D68 K52   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   1   0   0   0   0   0
8   8q 1 E12       0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0
9   9r 0 F48 I10   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   1   0   0
10 10v 1 H12       0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0
11 11x 0 Z83       0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1
12 12l 1     B18   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
```

Answer (score 0):

I have a package [{dplyover}](https://timteafan.github.io/dplyover/) on github which helps to solve this kind of problems without data rectangling (pivoting). To make it work we first need to convert the empty cells `""` into `NA`s. Then we can use `dplyover::dist_values` to get the unique values without `NA`s and loop over them to create new columns. We need to do this `rowwise`, since the values can be either in `dg1` or `dg2`.

```r
library(dplyr)
library(dplyover) # https://timteafan.github.io/dplyover/

df %>% 
  mutate(across(c(dg1, dg2), ~ ifelse(.x == "", NA_character_, .x))) %>% 
  rowwise %>% 
  mutate(over(dist_values(c(.$dg1, .$dg2)),
              ~ifelse(.x %in% c(dg1, dg2), 1, 0)))

#> # A tibble: 12 x 21
#> # Rowwise: 
#>    id        O dg1   dg2     A02   A84   B12   B18   C94   D12   D37   D68   E12
#>    <chr> <dbl> <chr> <chr> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#>  1 1a        1 A02   B18       1     0     0     1     0     0     0     0     0
#>  2 2c        1 A84   N34       0     1     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
#>  3 3d        0 B12   A02       1     0     1     0     0     0     0     0     0
#>  4 4f        1 C94   M01       0     0     0     0     1     0     0     0     0
#>  5 5g        1 D37   B12       0     0     1     0     0     0     1     0     0
#>  6 6e        0 D12   J02       0     0     0     0     0     1     0     0     0
#>  7 7f        0 D68   K52       0     0     0     0     0     0     0     1     0
#>  8 8q        1 E12   <NA>      0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     1
#>  9 9r        0 F48   I10       0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
#> 10 10v       1 H12   <NA>      0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
#> 11 11x       0 Z83   <NA>      0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
#> 12 12l       1 <NA>  B18       0     0     0     1     0     0     0     0     0
#> # … with 8 more variables: F48 <dbl>, H12 <dbl>, I10 <dbl>, J02 <dbl>,
#> #   K52 <dbl>, M01 <dbl>, N34 <dbl>, Z83 <dbl>
```

<sup>Created on 2022-03-24 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>